# Why is my pandas dataframe returning multipe headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a function to return a bunch of variables from a spreadsheet. I tried to return into a pandas dataframe instead of a tuple and got the result. Problem is It's returning the headers through every single row (See picture). Sorry if this is an easy fix, I'm quite new! Thank you!

In:

```
holdings_darray = ['01-03-2020','01-06-2020','01-07-2020','01-08-2020','01-09-2020','01-11-2020','01-14-2020','01-15-2020','01-17-2020','01-21-2020','01-22-2020','01-23-2020',
                   '01-24-2020','01-27-2020','01-28-2020','01-29-2020','01-30-2020','01-31-2020','02-04-2020']


def get_holdings_info(d):

    date = 0
    sbhmv = 0
    sbhbv = 0
    sbhs = 0

    setfhmv = 0
    setthbv = 0
    setfhs = 0

    smmhmv = 0
    smmhbv = 0
    smmhs = 0

    r = open('holdings/Holdings As Of ' + d + '.csv', 'r')
    line = r.readline()
    holdings_date = line[13:21]
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(holdings_date, "%Y%m%d")
    holdings_file = 'holdings/Holdings As Of ' + d + '.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(holdings_file, header=1)
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    account_names = ["fund1", "fund2"]
    bond_name = ["Bond Paying Periodic Income"]
    money_market_name = ["Money Market Fund"]
    mutual_fund_name = ["Mutual Fund"]
    sbh = df[df["Account Name"].isin(account_names) & df["Security Type Name"].isin(bond_name)]

    sbhmv = sbh['Market Value'].sum()
    sbhbv = sbh['Book Value'].sum()
    sbhs = sbh['Shares'].sum()
    setfh = df[df["Account Name"].isin(account_names) & df["Security Type Name"].isin(mutual_fund_name)]

    setfhmv = setfh['Market Value'].sum()
    setthbv = setfh['Book Value'].sum()
    setfhs = setfh['Shares'].sum()
    smmh = df[df["Account Name"].isin(account_names) & df["Security Type Name"].isin(money_market_name)]

    smmhmv = smmh['Market Value'].sum()
    smmhbv = smmh['Book Value'].sum()
    smmhs = smmh['Shares'].sum()
    return pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date], 'Bond Market Value':[sbhmv], 'Bond Book Value':[sbhbv], 'Bond Shares':[sbhs], 'ETF Market Value': [setfhmv], 'ETF Book Value' : [setthbv], 'ETF Shares': [setfhs], 'Money Market Market Value':[smmhmv], 'Money Market Book Value': [smmhbv], 'Money Market Shares':[smmhs]}
                        , columns=['Date', 'Bond Market Value', 'Bond Book Value', 'Bond Shares', 'ETF Market Value', 'ETF Book Value', 'ETF Shares', 'Money Market Market Value', 'Money Market Book Value', 'Money Market Shares'])

def get_holdings_info_array():
    c = []
    for f in holdings_darray:
        c.append(get_holdings_info(f))
    return(c)

print(get_holdings_info_array())
```

[pic of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbXaV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the thing is you write multiple DataFrames in your list `c`. If you print it, it will show you all dataframes listed. Instead you could add them to one dataframe:

```py
def get_holdings_info_array():
    c = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in holdings_darray:
        c = c.append(get_holdings_info(f), ignore_index=True)
    return(c)
```

Comment: ```TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'datetime.datetime'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid``` is what I got from that

Comment: well in that case your function does not seem to return a DataFrame.. can you show me what exactly `get_holdings_info(f)` is returning? And what type it is?

Answer (score 1):

hi you should try this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([date,sbhmv,sbhbv,sbhs,setfhmv,setthbv,setfhs,smmhmv,smmhbv,smmhs])
df = df.T
df.columns =['Date',
                  'Bond Market Value',
                  'Bond Book Value',
                  'Bond Shares',
                  'ETF Market Value',
                  'ETF Book Value', 
                  'ETF Shares',
                  'Money Market Market Value',
                  'Money Market Book Value',
                  'Money Market Shares']
return df
```

instead of :

```
     return pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date], 'Bond Market Value':[sbhmv], 'Bond Book Value':[sbhbv], 'Bond Shares':[sbhs], 'ETF Market Value': [setfhmv], 'ETF Book Value' : [setthbv], 'ETF Shares': [setfhs], 'Money Market Market Value':[smmhmv], 'Money Market Book Value': [smmhbv], 'Money Market Shares':[smmhs]}
                    , columns=['Date', 'Bond Market Value', 'Bond Book Value', 'Bond Shares', 'ETF Market Value', 'ETF Book Value', 'ETF Shares', 'Money Market Market Value', 'Money Market Book Value', 'Money Market Shares'])
```

Comment: ```ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 1), indices imply (10, 10)``` is what I got

Comment: replace columns = ["Date",...] with index = ['Date",...]

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a dataframe of 2 rows and 10 columns depicting the values. So you'll have to use

```
data = [date,sbhmv,sbhbv,sbhs,setfhmv,setthbv,setfhs,smmhmv,smmhbv,smmhs]
columns = ['Date','Bond Market Value','Bond Book Value','Bond Shares','ETF Market Value','ETF Book Value', 'ETF Shares','Money Market Market Value','Money Market Book Value','Money Market Shares']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns)
```

instead of:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date], 'Bond Market Value':[sbhmv], 'Bond Book Value':[sbhbv], 'Bond Shares':[sbhs], 'ETF Market Value': [setfhmv], 'ETF Book Value' : [setthbv], 'ETF Shares': [setfhs], 'Money Market Market Value':[smmhmv], 'Money Market Book Value': [smmhbv], 'Money Market Shares':[smmhs]}
                    , columns=['Date', 'Bond Market Value', 'Bond Book Value', 'Bond Shares', 'ETF Market Value', 'ETF Book Value', 'ETF Shares', 'Money Market Market Value', 'Money Market Book Value', 'Money Market Shares'])
```